# App doesn't asking for permissions on reinstall

Tags: android, permissions, backup

I have an application that has mandatory permission and they're being asked on start of the app after installation and start.

The problem occurs on the following case:

- App opens, asks for permissions
- Permissions granted, logins the user
- App deleted
- Reinstalled from apk file
- Does not asks for permissions
- Logins the user anyway

I've checked from application manager if permissions already granted automatically or some sort of backed-up, but they didn't.

Further info, I'm using "allowBackup=true" parameter on AndroidManifest. I'm facing this issue on Samsung Galaxy J5 Prime device.

Did any of you faced with this issue before, please help.

Thanks,

Comment: what happens if you uninstall and reboot the device then reinstall?

Comment: what is the logic of Login in your app? are you checking permission as well or the data from database/sharedpreferences ?  And if you check permissions of app in settings, are they enabled there by default on reinstall?

Comment: it has solved just by restarting the device, thanks